# Cannot use FakeHttpLayer of Robolectric (NullPointerException when calling getFakeHttpLayer)

Tags: java, android, robolectric

*Update 1*

After removing the `ServiceTestCase` extend of my test class, I edited my gradle file to change the `testInstrumentationRunner` to `org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner` but I get another error :

```
Running tests
Test running started
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodException'
Empty test suite.
```

I searched Google but I could not find out why I get this error message. Here is the whole gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "foo.bar.testappsdk"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19

        testApplicationId "novom.anyware.anywaresdk.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    sourceSets {
        instrumentTest.setRoot('src/androidTest')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'novom.anyware.anywaresdk:anywaresdk@aar'
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

*End of update 1*

---

I am trying to use Robolectric 2.4 to test the network calls of my Android Library. The problem is that I can't even get access to the FakeHttpLayer of Robolectric without getting a NullPointerException.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.robolectric.tester.org.apache.http.FakeHttpLayer org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowApplication.getFakeHttpLayer()' on a null object reference
at org.robolectric.Robolectric.getFakeHttpLayer(Robolectric.java:1239)
at novom.anyware.anywaresdk.test.AWRSyncServiceTest.test_3_get_config(AWRSyncServiceTest.java:61)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1837)
```

There is my Test class :

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class AWRSyncServiceTest extends ServiceTestCase<AWRSyncService> {
    private static final String TAG = "AWRSyncServiceTest";

    private AWRSyncService syncService;

    public AWRSyncServiceTest() {
        super(AWRSyncService.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        Log.d(TAG, "setUp");
        super.setUp();
        IBinder service = bindService(new Intent(getContext(), AWRSyncService.class));
        AWRSyncService.SyncServiceBinder binder = (AWRSyncService.SyncServiceBinder) service;
        syncService = binder.getService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        Log.d(TAG, "tearDown");
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void test_1_preconditions() {
        Log.d(TAG, "test_1_preconditions");
        assertNotNull(syncService);
        assertNotNull(syncService.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public void test_3_get_config() {
        Robolectric.getFakeHttpLayer();
    }

}
```

Am I missing some basic configuration that must be set to Robolectric before being able to use it? I can't find any good tutorial that would help me to understand what I did wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, I gave up on Robolectric.

Comment: So did you got any other framework for mocking rest api calls ? Can you please guide me ?

Comment: No, after losing 2 days of trying to get some unit testing on my project, I had not enough time to continue in this direction...

Comment: Okay no problem. Thanks for you time. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is why you have this specific problem, but one issue is that you are extending a `ServiceTestCase`. This is a problem, because you are now mixing Robolectric with Android Unit Tests.

Robolectric tests run on the JVM, not on device. Android Unit Tests ran on device.

You might also want to check this out in terms of how to test your service: http://robolectric.org/starting-components/

Comment: I also tried without Android Unit Tests, but I can't get it to find my tests... I keep getting this error message `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in novom.anyware.anywaresdk.test.AWRSyncServiceTest` and I did not find any tutorial that helped me resolve this. I think it will be easier to just keep using Android Unit Tests and refactor my code a little to be able to mock my networks calls.

Comment: Did you do an @Test annotation for your tests? JUnit4 does not match them by method name like JUnit 3.

Comment: Yes, I have two tests that have the `@Test` annotation but it's no use.

Comment: It seems like you have a different problem then, the issue is not that you can't use fake http layer, but that you're not able to build correctly with Robolectric. How are you building this, gradle? If yes, could you show your build.gradle file?

Comment: Yes, I added it to my post.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's because you are extending it from ServiceTestCase class. Don't use Android Unit Test suite for that. Also be sure you have created that class on JUnit 4.

Another thing is you should build the service with Robolectric way. Like this;

```html
Robolectric.buildService(AWRSyncService.class).bind()
```

EDIT : Add these fields to your build.gradle file, these are from [robolectric gradle plugin](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.13.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'robolectric'

android {
sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        setRoot('src/androidTest')
    }
}

robolectric {
    include '**/*Test.class'
}
```

Comment: Your answer is very similar to the one Alex Florescu already gave. I am not able to get Android Studio to find my tests... My class now extends no other class, has the `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)` annotation, I build my service with `Robolectric.buildService` and my tests have the `@Test` annotation but I keep getting the error message `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in novom.anyware.anywaresdk.test.AWRSyncServiceTest`

Comment: I tried to edit gradle files to fit what you gave for example, but I keep getting errors of gradle versions... And I don't really want to completely change my gradle files, since I need them to build my app that test my library and I also have a test file that uses the Android Unit Test instruments. Integrating Robolectric is way too complicated for what it gives, I'd rather refactor my classes to use the Android Unit Test instruments. I tried for more than a day to use Robolectric without success... I don't like it. Thank you for your help